# Zend_Search_Lucene tries to allocate 3503812093817007931 bytes

Tags: php, zend-framework, search, lucene

I have around 250kb of static HTML that I have to search through. I figured I would use Zend Lucene for that. Creating indexes takes a few secs and all is nice and good except if I search for "about" it ends up with this:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 
3503812093817007931 bytes) in /var/www/u1938159/data/www/-----
/protected/vendors/Zend/Search/Lucene/Storage/File/Filesystem.php on line 163
```

Other words seem to be ok for it. Moreover, the files contain some foreign texts. So I have to use case insensitive analyzer

```
Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer::setDefault(
    new Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer_Common_Utf8_CaseInsensitive()
);
Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_QueryParser::setDefaultEncoding('utf-8');
```

In which case it takes an eternity to load and doesn't work at all crashing with this:

```
Error occured while file reading.
```

Does Lucene have serious issues or did I messs something up myself?

Comment: How many html files are there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lucene doesn't have these issues, but `Zend_Search_Lucene` has. I'm not sure how much you have to search and if this is a one time thing, but I'd look into [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) or [ElasticSearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/).

Can you extend your question with some data?

There are also a couple hosted services, let me know if you need more pointers.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what the specific problem with Zend Lucene is here, but if you're trying to search through a relatively small HTML file, you might want to try just using grep.  For example, on the command line:

`cat file.html | grep -i about` to find lines containing the word about.

or

`cat file.html | grep -i -o -P '.{30}About.{30}'` if you want just 30 characters on either side of the word about.

Comment: Downvoted because the answer is irrelevant to the question. He wasn't asking for alternative ways to search - he was asking how to solve a specific error.